# How can I use data in the child component that are updated in parent component using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

My parent component looks like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <PaymentMethod/>
        ...
        <b-btn class="float-right" variant="primary" @click="add">
             OK
        </b-btn>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        methods: {
            add() {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My child component looks like :

```
<template>
    ...
        <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="methodOptions" />
        ...
        <b-form-select v-model="termSelected" :options="termOptions" />
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                selected: null,
                termSelected: null
            }
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

If the `add` method called from parent component, I want it get data selected in the child component

How can I do it?

Comment: You emit it, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the `sync` modifier along with computed getters and setters:

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
    ...
        <PaymentMethod :method.sync="method" :term.sync="term"/>
        ...
        <b-btn class="float-right" variant="primary" @click="add">
             OK
        </b-btn>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                method: null,
                term: null
            }
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```
<template>
    ...
        <b-form-select v-model="_method" :options="methodOptions" />
        ...
        <b-form-select v-model="_term" :options="termOptions" />
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['method', 'term'],
        computed: {
            _method: {
               get () {
                   return this.method
               },
               set (value) {
                   this.$emit('update:method', value)
               }
            },
            _term: {
               get () {
                   return this.term
               },
               set (value) {
                   this.$emit('update:term', value)
               }
            },
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Now with the parent component's `add` method you have access to the child's selected `method` and `term` options:

```
methods: {
    add() {
        // this.method is the value of _method 
        // this.term is the value of _term
    }
}
```

**Update**

Since you've stated you want both the value and text of the selected term / method, I would suggest the following changes:

**Parent**

```
<template>
    ...
        <PaymentMethod :methods="methods" 
                       :terms="terms"  
                       :method.sync="method" 
                       :term.sync="term"/>
        ...
        <b-btn class="float-right" variant="primary" @click="add">
             OK
        </b-btn>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                // define your method and term arrays in the parent component.
                // pass them as props to the child component.
                methods: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
                terms: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
                method: null,
                term: null
            }
        },
        // use computed properties to retrieve the selected method / term option.
        computed: {
            selectedMethod () {
                return this.methods.find(method => method.value === this.method)
            },
            selectedTerm () {
                return this.terms.find(term => term.value === this.term)
            },
        }
        ...
    }
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
    ...
        <b-form-select v-model="_method" :options="methods" />
        ...
        <b-form-select v-model="_term" :options="terms" />
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['method', 'term', 'methods', 'terms'],
        computed: {
            _method: {
               get () {
                   return this.method
               },
               set (value) {
                   this.$emit('update:method', value)
               }
            },
            _term: {
               get () {
                   return this.term
               },
               set (value) {
                   this.$emit('update:term', value)
               }
            },
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Great. But there are still shortcomings. This code : `this.$emit('term', value)`. Should `this.$emit('update:term', value)`

Comment: Can I get text from each option when selected? If I use your way, I only get the value of each option. I want to take the text too

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: To do so you would need to do something like 1) fire an event with the selected object - `this.$emit('selected-term', this.terms.find(term => term.value === value))` - instead of `this.$emit('update:term', value)` and then manually update the prop in the parent component, or 2), pass the methods and terms as props also to the child component and when the update event fires, search for the respective term/method in the parent, as shown in the first example. Both similar but #2 would be easier to implement, IMO. Vuex/shared state would also be a good choice.

Comment: I try your update answer and change data in parent component like this : `methods: [], terms: []`. In `selectedMethod` computed I add `console.log(this.methods)`.  And then I try to select the method. There is no result

Answer (score 1):

Use Vuex, your store.js will look like :

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import Vuex from 'vuex';
   Vue.use(Vuex);


 const state = {
    selected: null
 };
 const mutations = {
    SET_SELECTED(state, selected) {
    state.selected =selected;
   }
   }

 export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
   mutations
   })
```

in app.js :

```
import store from './vuex/store';
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
store,
...})
```

in parent component :

```
    <template>
     ...
   <PaymentMethod :selected="selected" />
     ...
        <b-btn class="float-right" variant="primary" @click="add">
        OK
        </b-btn>
     ...
    </template>
  <script>
   export default {
    data(){
     returen {
       selected:null    
     }
     },
    methods: {
        add() {
         ...
       this.$store.commit("SET_SELECTED",this.selected) 
      }
    }
 }
 </script>
```

in child component :

```
   <template>
     ...
     <b-form-select @change="selectItem" v-model="selected" 
             :options="methodOptions" />
   ...
 </template>
<script>
  export default {
   data () {
    return {
      selected:null
    }
 },
 methods:{
   selectItem(){
    this.$store.commit("SET_SELECTED",this.selected
    }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: There exist error : `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "selected"`

Comment: yes, you could bind `v-model` to a property in your data object called `selectedProp`

Comment: But with you solution he still can't change `this.selected` in child component. When you use `v-model` you should implement getter and setter.

Comment: @boussadjra brahim, It does not work. If I `console.log(this.selectedInParent)` in add method, the result is `null`

Comment: @xneg You better answer this question

Comment: @SuccessMan your question wasn't clear, try to update it

Comment: @SuccessMan ok, i updated my answer to exchange data from parent to child and vice-versa

Comment: @boussadjra brahim Seems it works. But what if I have 2 select? Try to see my question. I had update it

Comment: you could create a data object property to each component, but if there's many you could use an array and loop using v-for

Comment: @boussadjra brahim The look was complicated using your way

Comment: so you could use Vuex

Comment: i'm updating y question using vuex

Comment: @boussadjra brahim Okay. Maybe later I will use vuex. If I try your way above. If I select first, the result is null. If I choose the second and so on, there is a result. Sometimes the results are not appropriate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180082/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-success-man).

Answer (score 0):

The best and recommended way is using $emit 
The bellow example could show you how? < /br>

```js
Vue.component('child-tmp', {
  props: ['post'],
  template: `
  <button @click="$emit('add-like')">Like</button>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    posts: [{
      title: "Heading goes here 1",
      content: "Something sadofnd idfidif disong.",
      likes: 0
    },
    {
      title: "Heading 2 goes here",
      content: "Something sadofnd idfidif disong.",
      likes: 0
    }],
    totalLikes: 0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Posts:</h2>
  <section>
    <div v-for="post in posts">
      <h2>
        {{post.title}}
      </h2>
      <p>
        {{post.content}}
      </p>
      <child-tmp v-bind:post="post" v-on:add-like="post.likes = post.likes+1"></child-tmp><span style="margin-left:10px;">{{post.likes}}</span>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

In the above snippet you could see we are using props to read the data from parent to child and we use $emit to pass the data from child and v-on:add-like to receive the emitted data.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways:

**1. You can either emit event when selecting data in child component:**

```
<template>
    ...
        <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="methodOptions" />
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                selected: null
            }
        },
        ...
        methods: {
          onSelect() {
            this.$emit('selectData', this.selected);
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and then handle this event in parent component:

```
<template>
    ...
        <PaymentMethod @selectData="changeChildData($event)"/>
        ...
        <b-btn class="float-right" variant="primary" @click="add">
             OK
        </b-btn>

    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        data() {
            return {
              childData: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeChildData(newData) {
              this.childData = newData;
            },
            add() {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**2. or you can use storage [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)**

or event bus (simplified version of Vuex):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

you pass data from child to event bus

```
<script>
    import { EventBus } from '../EventBus.js';
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                selected: null
            }
        },
        ...
        methods: {
          onSelect() {
            EventBus.$emit('selectData', this.selected);
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and subscribe from parent for it change

```
<script>
    import { EventBus } from '../EventBus.js';
    export default {
        ...
        data() {
            return {
              childData: null
            }
        },
        created() {
            EventBus.$on('selectData', (data) => {
                this.childData = data;
            });
        },
        methods: {
            add() {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You first way is not work. If I `console.log('test')` in the `onSelect` method and I select the option, there is no result

Comment: @SuccessMan don't understand connection with `console.log()`. It doesn't affect the code in any way. I took this fragment from my working code. Maybe some typos but it works for me.

Comment: @SuccessMan i modified code for parent a bit introducing new method. Try to test this varian and ensure that method `changeChildData` called.

Comment: Your first example is exactly what the [sync](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) modifier is for. Equating Vuex to an event bus is a gross oversimplification and misses the point of a reactive state system.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter didn't know about `sync`. Seems it's a new feature. Thank you!